# Animation Block Conversion to Swift (class function)

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

In a type methods class `ToolsCustomFunctions` I have

```
class func labelAnimation()->UILabel{

         //Start animation settings
         self.labelAnimation().transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(4, 4);

         UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2,
                             delay: 0.0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.6,
             initialSpringVelocity: 0.8,
            options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut,

            animations:{

                //Animate

                self.labelAnimation().transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)


            }, completion: { finished in


                //Animation complete


        })
        return (labelAnimation())



      }
```

Im using this to perform animation of text in various views using

```
someLabel  =  ToolsCustomFunctions.labelAnimation()
```

This is giving me EXC_BAD_ACESS on `class func labelAnimation()->UILabel{`  Im assuming in swift im not handling this correctly in my class function, the question is what?

Answer (score 0):

First, Your `labelAnimation` method is calling itself recursively (and not just once, but in three places), resulting in a stack overflow. Second, If you're planning to set the `transform` property of a view relative to `self`, then why is `labelAnimation` a class method rather than an instance method?

To fix this, remove the `class` keyword from the first line, and replace `labelAnimation()` in the rest of the code with the name of a property (without the parens) that actually contains a `UILabel` instance.

One other observation: it doesn't appear to make sense to have a method that triggers an animation return a view. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Its a class method method because its a custom function method i'm using to animate labels throughout the app.